# Set Values in column B based on values in Column A in SQL2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, etl

I'm trying to take an existing column and parse each row for certain words in a string, i.e. Sheet, Page, Card, and based on that word (only one instance of one of these words is in a row) populate a new column in the same table with a value.  If it did not find any of those words, leave Column B blank.

I.E.  Column A contains the word "Sheet", populate Column B with the letter "S"

So the table would be something like:

```
Column A  Column B
Sheet        S
Page         P
Card         C
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET ColumnB = CASE WHEN ColumnA LIKE '%Sheet%' THEN 'S'
                       WHEN ColumnA LIKE '%Page%' THEN 'P'
                       WHEN ColumnA LIKE '%Card%' THEN 'C'
                       ELSE NULL /* or '' if you prefer */
                  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH mappings (ColumnA, ColumnB) AS
(
 SELECT 'Sheet','S' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Page','P' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Card','C' 
)
UPDATE y
SET y.ColumnB= m.ColumnB
FROM YourTable y
JOIN mappings m ON y.ColumnA LIKE '%' + m.ColumnA + '%'
```

Comment: Edge case perhaps, but this wouldn't blank out ColumnB if it previously contained a value that was no longer valid.

Comment: @Joe - That isn't in the spec! The question says "leave Column B blank" implying that it does not currently contain any non blank items.

Comment: You're right and, as I said, at best it's an edge case to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried both and both worked well in my case, however in case someone in the future finds this I gave the check to Joe's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
update myTable 
set columnB = substring(columnA, 1, 1)
```

Comment: If you want it to be always upper case you can change the substring part to :  upper(substring(columnA, 1, 1))

Comment: It doesnt address the problem, he wants only on Sheet, Page, Card values otherwise null. This is just getting the first character from A to B.